# WPF - Edit Database via TableAdapter, DataContext/Dataview and DataGrid to TextBox

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I've done some search and was unable to find any working answer. Actually it's three questions (I'm using the WPF btw).

1 - I have a database and I'm using TableAdapters to insert data into it and showing in a dataGrid. The Insert function works perfect, but the edit and delete doesn't work. When I change or delete some record, it does change in the datagrid, but when I restart the program both the changes(edit or delete) aren't saved, and I've no idea why, i've already changed the properties of copy database and the others like that. Here is my edit code:

```
 private void ButtonEditAtiv_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

        string nomeIns = nomeTextBox.Text;
        string emailIns = emailTextBox.Text;
        string telefoneIns = telefoneTextBox.Text;
        string enderecoIns = endereçoTextBox.Text;
        string dataNascIns = dataNascimentoDatePicker.SelectedDate.ToString();
        InstrutorTableAdapter instrutorTA = new InstrutorTableAdapter();
        try
        {
            instrutorTA.Update(this.academiaSQLDS.Instrutor);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
```

2 - For getting the selected datagrid line data to the textboxes I'm using a DataView/DataContext code:

```
private CollectionView dataView;
        internal CollectionView DataView
        {
            get
            {
                if (dataView == null)
                {
                    dataView = (CollectionView)
                        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(
                        this.DataContext);
                }
                return dataView;
            }
        }
```

This one actually works great for getting the selected data, but I doesn't know if this is the right way to do that, since none of the others I found worked this great. There is another way to get the selected datagrid line and put it in textboxes to edit the data and etc?

P.S: I'm using a .mdf local SQL Database.

Comment: This looks like a good question, but I don't know the Microsoft technologies. If you log on again and are still looking for an answer, ping me using `@halfer` for a question bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ItemSource` instead of `DataContext` then on the `xaml textbox Text"{Binding @Col1}"`

So here is what I do..
on the xaml `DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"`

on the xaml `Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Grade, ElementName=dataGrid1}"`

assuming your getting the datagrid showing up the data then the above is all you need to populate the textboxes.

Please mark as answer complete.